# I can't use FileDownloadHandler on TeamCity agent

Tags: windows-server-2003, teamcity, watin

I have some trouble to run the `FileDownloadHandler` on my TeamCity agent.

Configuration:

- windows server 2003
- internet explorer 7
- TeamCity Agent run as console

I have a very simple test:

```
using (new UseDialogOnce(Browser.DialogWatcher, handler))
{
   Browser.Button(Find.ById("ButtonExportReport")).Click();
   handler.WaitUntilFileDownloadDialogIsHandled(10);
   handler.WaitUntilDownloadCompleted(20);
}
```

When I am logged with TeamCity user (so my status is `Active` in the task manager user tab), everything works. If I disconnect (without logging off, so my status is `Disconnected` in the task manager user tab), it doesn't work. I get

```
WatiN.Core.Exceptions.WatiNException: Has not shown dialog after 10 seconds.
```

Do you know what I could do ? I give up about investigating in WatiN source code, I try now to setup my server so the user session is always `Active`. Do you know else what I could do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more investigation, I understood that WatiN need a real user logged directly on the server. So I configure the AutoLogin in windows 2003 server following this instruction: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324737/en-us. So the server automatically logs as TeamCity user when it starts.

After, I disable the TeamCity Service and put in the Startup folder of the TeamCity user this batch file:

```
cd c:\BuildAgent\bin
agent.bat start
```

So it starts the agent when it logs, so at start up.